# Is there a way to create a struct from a slice in golang

Tags: csv, go, struct, slice, record

I need to read a csv record which has many fields and convert to struct. Currently I am doing as below

```
//Proclog is type to hold
type Proclog struct {
    LogType       string `json:"LogType"`
    RootLogID     string `json:"RootLogId"`
    SubLogID      string `json:"SubLogId"`
    TransactionID string `json:"TransactionId"`
    Instance      string `json:"Instance"`
    Operation     string `json:"Operation"`
    Status        string `json:"Status"`
    User          string `json:"User"`
    Hostname      string `json:"Hostname"`
    Protocol      string `json:"Protocol"`
    Target        string `json:"Target"`
    StartTime     string `json:"StartTime"`
    ExecuteTime   string  `json:"ExecuteTime"`
    ResponseCode  string `json:"ResponseCode"`
    FullRequest   string `json:"FullRequest"`
    FullResponse  string `json:"FullResponse"`
}

//ProclogFromCsvRecord convert csv record to LogConsolidation
func ProclogFromCsvRecord(record []string) (*Proclog, error) {
    if len(record) != 17 {
        return nil, csv.ErrFieldCount
    }
    return &Proclog{
        LogType:       record[0],
        RootLogID:     record[1],
        SubLogID:      record[2],
        TransactionID: record[3],
        Instance:      record[4],
        Operation:     record[5],
        Status:        record[6],
        User:          record[7],
        Hostname:      record[8],
        Protocol:      record[9],
        Target:        record[10],
        StartTime:     record[11],
        ExecuteTime:   record[12],
        ResponseCode:  record[13],
        FullRequest:   record[14],
        FullResponse:  record[15],
    }, nil
}
```

I don't want to hard code the index, is there a better way to convert a slice into struct without hard coding index?

Comment: use yourself defined `tag` ?  Like  ```LogType  string `json:"LogType" mytag:"1"`  ````

Comment: There is no native way to do this. You can use package like this https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think your code is perfectly fine as you wrote it. Your code must contain the field order in one way or another, and you can't make it much simpler than you did, which is nice.

If anything, you could specify the field order using *iota*.

```golang
type ProclogField int

const (
        LogType ProclogField = iota
        RootLogID
        SubLogID
        TransactionID
        Instance
        Operation
        Status
        User
        Hostname
        Protocol
        Target
        StartTime
        ExecuteTime
        ResponseCode
        FullRequest
        FullResponse
        ProclogLength
)
```

Now you can replace the number literals in your code by these constants when creating the Proclog struct.

If you can live without an actual struct, you can define a type directly from the slice, like this:

```golang
type Proclog []string

func (p Proclog) Get(f ProclogField) string {
        return p[f]
}

func ProclogFromCsvRecord(record []string) (Proclog, error) {
        if len(record) != int(ProclogLength)+1 {
                return nil, csv.ErrFieldCount
        }
        return Proclog(record), nil
}
```

Then, if you need to convert this type to JSON, you can implement the json.Marshaler interface like this:

```golang
//go:generate stringer -type=ProclogField
func (p Proclog) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
        m := make(map[string]string)
        for z := ProclogField(0); z < ProclogLength; z++ {
                m[z.String()] = p.Get(z)
        }
        return json.Marshal(m)
}
```

However, this is not what you asked for and I'm not convinced that all of this is better than the simple code you started with.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
)

type People struct {
    Name   string `mytag:"0"`
    Age    int    `mytag:"1"`
    Nunber int64  `mytag:"2"`
}

func FieldsArrayToStruct(p interface{}, values []interface{}) {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(p).Elem()
    length := len(values)
    for i := 0; i < rv.NumField(); i++ {
        tagValue, ok := rv.Type().Field(i).Tag.Lookup("mytag")
        typeName := rv.Type().Field(i).Type.Name()
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        if tagValue == "" {
            continue
        }
        index, err := strconv.Atoi(tagValue)
        if err != nil || index < 0 || index > length-1 {
            continue
        }
        switch values[i].(type) {
        case int:
            if typeName == "int" || typeName == "int32" || typeName == "int64" {
                rv.FieldByIndex(rv.Type().Field(i).Index).SetInt(int64(values[i].(int)))
            }
        case string:
            if typeName == "string" {
                rv.FieldByIndex(rv.Type().Field(i).Index).SetString(values[i].(string))
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var p = &People{}
    FilesArrayToStruct(p, []interface{}{"Tom", 19, 11110})
    log.Println(p)
}
```

maybe you need continue finish `func FieldsArrayToStruct`'s `switch`block.